# What are the different monster attributes?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

When I look at a monster it has several attributes listed with it.  I understand the "early starter", "late starter" ones, but there are others that don't really seem to be defined anywhere.  Things like "Meleeproof" or "Noisy".  What do these attributes mean, and is there a way to view the definitions in game?  Does a monster's type determine its attributes, or can they change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three most important imo are

```
Term         | Meaning                     
----------------------------------------------
Early Peaker | The Monster can reach a maximum level of 20       
Well-Grown   | The Monster can reach a maximum level of 30 to 60    
Late Bloomer | The Monster can reach a maximum level of 70 to 90
```

The rest all make sense based on what they are called. Examples: Hearty means the monster will have a higher HP than a monster without it. Strong means a monster will have higher strength. Pinch Hitter means the monster can learn abilities that can be activated when in danger, etc.

There are some that are *element*+prone which means the monster is weaker against that element. Some are *element*+proof which means the monster has a strong resistance to that element or will learn resistance abilities for that element.

For completeness: As mentioned by Yuck, only the first three attributes define the monster. The fourth attribute has no in game effect for your monster and is there for fun. See Yuck's answer for more information.

Comment: That looks like a good list, but I'm pretty sure I have seen Noisy, so I'm wondering if its incomplete.  I assume Noisy increases the chance to interrupt an enemy...

Comment: Ah, @Yuck's answer seems to explain this.

Answer (score 3):

> > **Early Peaker**: maximum level of 20
> >     **Well Grown**: max level 30 to 60
> >     **Late bloomer**: max level 70 to 99
> >     **Hearty**: high hp growth
> >     **Strong**: high strength growth
> >     **Magical**: high magical growth
> >     **Balanced**: balanced parameter growth
> >     **Brainy**: learns many abilities
> >     **Flameprone**: weak to fire
> >     **Frostprone**: weak to ice
> >     **Sparkprone**: weak to lightning
> >     **Windprone**: weak to wind
> >     **Flameproof**: strong fire resistance or learns fire resistance abilities
> >     **Frostproof**: strong ice resistance/learns ice resistance abilities
> >     **Thunderproof**: strong lightning resistance/learns lightning resistance abilities
> >     **Windproof**: strong wind resistance/learns wind resistance abilities
> >     **Meleeproof**: strong physical resistance/learns physical resistance abilities
> >     **Manaproof**: strong magic resistance/learns magic resistance abilities
> >     **Venomproof**: strong poison resistance/learns poison resistance abilities
> >     **Fogproof**: strong fog resistance/learns fog resistance abilities
> >     **Painproof**: strong pain resistance/learns pain resistance abilities
> >     **Hexproof**: strong curse resistance/learns curse resistance abilities
> >     **Wimpy**: has multiple weaknesses
> >     **Stoic**: has numerous resistances/learns many resistance based abilities
> >     **Resourceful**: learns abilities that improves post battle rewards
> >     **Pinch hitter**: learns abilities that can be activated when in danger
> >     **Loyal**: learns abilities that will be activated when allies are in danger
> >     **Zippy**: speedy monster with abilities such as auto:haste or critical:haste
> >     **Rare**: difficult to encounter or recruit

Source: https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/61822400

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Adanion's answer the fourth attribute listed is just for fun. It has no in-game effect and is just meant to be cute or entertaining. Some of these are actually *Cute*, *Zippy*, and so on.

Only the first three attributes define the monster.