# Is there a list of the monster descriptions and what they do?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the different monster attributes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50682/what-are-the-different-monster-attributes)

A lot of monsters have attributes that weren't really explained in the tutorial. The tutorial explained "well-grown", "early-peaker", and "late-bloomer", but not the other ones like "Hex-proof" or "thunder-proof".

Is there a list of these and their effects anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is available in the in-game database (only played the Japanese version), but if you are willing to look outside the game, this [guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/faqs/63731) on Gamefaqs can help.